# How to add a logo over video using libvlc options in Android

Tags: android, video, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to add a logo over a video in Android, I tried to do:

```
String[] options = {"--sub-filter=logo" ,"--logo-file=/mnt/sdcard/video.png"};

playMRL(mLibVlcInstance, mrl, options);
```

but it did not add a logo, in Windows it works:

```
vlc --sub-filter=logo --logo-file=video.png movie.mp4
```

Does anybody have any idea how to run with these options in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I've found the options in a sample from https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample in this way:

```
ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
//options.add("--subsdec-encoding <encoding>");
options.add("--aout=opensles");
options.add("--audio-time-stretch"); // time stretching
options.add("-vvv"); // verbosity
libvlc = new LibVLC(options);
```

but AFAIK not all the functionality of libVLC is exposed by the android port, as is stated in this answer: [Video rotation on android using LibVLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672155/video-rotation-on-android-using-libvlc)